# variable is not defined en JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un input dinamico que dibujo con

```
for (var j = 0; j < valorCantidad; j++) {
    contador = contador + 1;
    jQuery('#tblTabla1 tr:last').after('<tr>' +
        '<td align="center" class="valorId">' + contador + '</td>' +
        '<td align="center" class="valorInt">' + valorInterno + '</td>' +
        '<td align="center" class="valorFa">' + valorFa + '</td>' +
        '<td align="center" class="valorArt">' + valorAr + '</td>' +
        '<td align="center">'+
            '<input type="text" id="numeroSerie-' + contador + '" name="Serie" placeholder="Ingrese número de serie" class="form-control" onblur="validacionSeries(numeroSerie-' + contador + ');" />'+
            '<div id="divError-' + contador + '"></div>'+
        '</td>'+
    '</tr>');
```

y esta es mi funcion

```
<script>
    function validacionSeries(txt) {
        alert("ok"+txt);
        var m = document.getElementById(valorTxt).value;
        alert(m);
        var expreg = new RegExp("^[0-9]{15,19}$");

        if (expreg.test(m)) {
            alert("ok");
        } else {
            alert("no");
        };
    };
</script>
```

como se ve le agrego al textbox un metodo JS `onblur="validacionSeries(numeroSerie-' + contador + ');"`, pero me manda un mensaje de `numeroSerie` que no esta definida, no entiendo por que, si le quito la variable que paso como parámetro a la función se ejecuta bien (solo que coloco en la función sin parámetro un `alert`).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que estás viendo se debe a que `numeroSerie-1` no es un nombre de variable válido en JavaScript, el caracter `-` lo toma como el operador de resta.

Por otro lado veo que estás asignando el evento directamente al elemento `<input>` a través del atributo `onblur`.  Es recomendable que evites asignar los manejadores de eventos directamente sobre elemento, en vez de eso es mejor asignarlos por código, así mantienes algo más limpia la estructura HTML.

En tu caso específico inclusive puedes crear un solo manejador de eventos que maneje todas las filas.  Aquí un ejemplo mínimo:

```js
function validacion(txt) {
  return /^[0-9]{15,19}$/.test(txt);
};

$('#tblTabla1').on('blur', '.serie', function(event) {
  var input = $(event.target);
  var txt = input.val();
  var span = input.next('.error');
  span.toggle(!validacion(txt));
});

for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    $('#tblTabla1 tr:last').after('<tr>' +
        '<td>' + i + '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
            '<input class="serie" />'+
            '<span class="error" style="display:none">Error</span>'+
        '</td>' +
    '</tr>'); 
}
```

```css
.error {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblTabla1">
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Esta muy bien elaborado asi lo queria tener pero no me salia, muchas gracias, esta excelente =)

Answer (score 2):

Por partes:

El ejemplo que pones esta incompleto, intenta ponerlo más completo. Entre otras cosas ayudaría a saber que es lo que quieres hacer (y a que propongamos mejores soluciones).

En este caso, te da el error por que cuando haces

```
'... onblur="validacionSeries(numeroSerie-' + contador + ');"'
```

ese `numeroSerie` que debería ser un string, no está como tal.

Para ver un poco la idea te lo he modificado un poco, no me parece la mejor solución pero ahí te dejo lo que he cambiado (no he mirado que querias hacer despues, además de que el `valorTxt` no se que es)

https://jsfiddle.net/8L34qtg6/

No se si aún quieres meter el `numeroSerie` como String en la función, de ser así, lo dicho, tiene que estar como String

Un saludo

Comment: Gracias, así lo tenia y no me lo reconocía el navegador, hasta apenas hoy que intente otravez, no se que paso pero hoy si funciono =)

Answer (score 1):

si lo que andas buscando es como validar el patrón `^[0-9]{15,19}$` lo podemos hacer mediante `HTML5` lo que a la fecha esta bien soportado: http://caniuse.com/#search=pattern en el código mira como esta definido `myElementToAdd`

```js
var contador = 1;
function agregarInput(){
var myElementToAdd = '<input type="text" id="numeroSerie-' + contador + '" name="Serie" placeholder="Ingrese número de serie" class="form-control" pattern="^[0-9]{15,19}$" />'
$('#resultado').append(myElementToAdd);
}

   function validacionSeries(txt) {
        alert("ok"+txt);
        var m = document.getElementById(valorTxt).value;
        alert(m);
        var expreg = new RegExp("^[0-9]{15,19}$");

        if (expreg.test(m)) {
            alert("ok");
        } else {
            alert("no");
        };
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="agregarInput()">agregar input</button>
<div id=resultado></div>
```